# Converting string to javascript dictionary

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I have a string like this which is retrieved from a database. I need to convert the string to a Javascript dictionary.

```
"['content':{'type':'file','path':'callie/circle'},'video':{'videoId':'CvIr-2lMLsk','startSeconds': 15,'endSeconds': 30'}]".
```

How do I convert the above string to a Javascript dictionary? Should I convert the string to json first or not? When I try `json.parse`, an error is shown:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
>   at Object.parse (native)
>   at :2:6
>   at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (:905:140)
>   at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (:838:34)
>   at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (:694:21)

Comment: Did you tried using Map?

Comment: how can i use map for this .? i have no idea

Comment: That is not JSON. Strings need to be in *double quotes*, not single quotes.

Comment: Valid json string is: 
{"content":{"path":"callie/circle","type":"file"},"video":{"videoId":"CvIr-2lMLsk","endSeconds":"30'","startSeconds":15}}

I suggest you to create correct json string first.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Please correct your JSON string,

```
Valid json is: {"content":{"path":"callie/circle","type":"file"},"video":{"videoId":"CvIr-2lMLs‌​k","endSeconds":"30","startSeconds":15}}
```

Then convert string to JSON as:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
```

What I tried:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"content":{"path":"callie/circle","type":"file"},"video":{"videoId":"CvIr-2lMLs‌​k","endSeconds":"30","startSeconds":15}}');
console.log(obj.content);
var obj2 = obj.content;
console.log(obj2.path);
```

Comment: how can i use incorrect json string,just pure js dict ?  {}

Comment: like {url:xxxx}